# SyntaxError: The requested module 'sqlite' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm

i am having trouble when trying to import sqlite, I add the following line:

```
import sqlite from 'sqlite';
```

and I get the following error

```
file:///D:/WebPro/WebProg/cwCode/dbInteract.js:2
import sqlite from 'sqlite';
       ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'sqlite' does not provide an export named 'default'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:105:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:151:5)
    at async Loader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:166:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:68:5)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\WebPro\WebProg\cwCode
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node svr.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rory\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-04T13_37_27_066Z-debug.log
PS D:\WebPro\WebProg\cwCode>
```

I did not have this problem before I changed the type in the package.json to 'module'

If I then change is to

```
import sqlite from 'sqlite3';
```

i get this error instead

```
file:///D:/WebPro/WebProg/cwCode/svr.js:4
const express = require('express');
                ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///D:/WebPro/WebProg/cwCode/svr.js:4:17
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:154:23)
    at async Loader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:166:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:68:5)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\WebPro\WebProg\cwCode
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node svr.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rory\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-04T13_44_05_322Z-debug.log
PS D:\WebPro\WebProg\cwCode>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ESM modules, there are two ways to export functionnalities: either as default exports, or as named exports. The way you import these functionnalities depends on how they are actually exported in the first place.

```
import defaultExport from 'module1'                  // Import default export 
import { namedExport1, namedExport2 } from 'module2' // Import named exports
```

Note a module may actually have both a default and named exports, or just either one of them.

Even though they are libraries for the same database, the `sqlite` and `sqlite3` packages apparently just export their apis in different ways - and `sqlite` more specifically doesn't seem to have a default export.

Also, when you set your `package.json` `type` key to `module`, you instruct node to load you program with the ESM module system. This system doesn't define a `require()` function - which is defined by the other node.js mainstream module system called CommonJS. You should just stick to the `import` syntax here.